# How to print a directory in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to ***print*** a directory "w:\dir\xx.doc" as the output in my rmarkdown output pdf file.

I have tried to:

1) directly write in text:

here is the directory w:\dir\xx.doc

2) try to print it in inline R-code:

here is the directory `r print("w:\dir\xx.doc")`

Does anyone know how to print the directory?

My problem is not about how to treat a directory in R, but how to properly print out a directory in my pdf file as a string in a common fomat as a directory. So actually I do not want to functionally call the directory in R, but just to properly print it out. for instance I would like to have a sentence in my file: "here is the location where we store the file: w:\dir\xx.doc"

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are being interpreted as escape sequences.
The easiest solution is to use `normalizePath()` to convert the path to a more unix-like representation:

`normalizePath(mydir, winslash = "/")`

R on windows will interpret forward slashes correctly.

Alternatively you can try using a double-backslash (\) to escape your backslash, but there are usually several levels where this needs escaping.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My problem is not about how to treat a directory in R, but how to properly print out a directory in my pdf file as a string in a common fomat as a directory. So actually I do not want to functionally call the directory, but just to properly print it out. for instance I would like to have a sentence in my file: "here is the location where we store the file: w:\dir\xx.doc"

Comment: The issue is still with the backslashes...  They get interpreted as escape characters in pandoc, latex, etc. so your path isn't getting printed correctly.  Converting the backslashes to forward slashes avoids this issue, and normalizePath provides a convenient tool for this.  The alternative is to do what @scoa and I both suggested, and escape with a double backslash- but I found that more problematic because there are several levels where escaping is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In R, backslash must be escaped; so each time you want to write `\` inside a string, you need to write `\\`.

```
mydir <- "w:\\dir\\xx.doc"
print(mydir)
# w:\\dir\\xx.doc
cat(mydir)
# w:\dir\xx.doc
```